# How do I construct a LINQ with multiple GroupBys?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public partial class MemberTank
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int Tier { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string TankName { get; set; }
    public int Battles { get; set; }
    public int Victories { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

A tiny sample of the data:

```
 Id   AccountId   Tier   Class  TankName   Battles  Victories
 ---  ---------   ----   -----  ---------  -------  ----------
 1    432423      5      Heavy  KV         105      58
 2    432423      6      Heavy  IS         70       39
 3    544327      5      Heavy  KV         200      102
 4    325432      7      Medium KV-13      154      110
 5    432423      7      Medium KV-13      191      101
```

Ultimately I am trying to get a result that is a list of tiers, within the tiers is a list of classes, and within the class is a distinct grouping of the TankName with the sums of Battles and Victories.

Is it possible to do all this in a single LINQ statement?  Or is there another way to easily get the result?  (I know I can easily loop through the DbSet several times to produce the list I want; I am hoping for a more efficient way of getting the same result with LINQ.)

Comment: Just using standard group by in linq should be fine for this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var output = from mt in MemberTanks
             group by {mt.Tier, mt.Class, mt.TankName} into g
             select new { g.Key.Tier, 
                          g.Key.Class, 
                          g.Key.TankName, 
                          Fights = g.Sum(mt => mt.Battles), 
                          Wins = g.Sum(mt=> mt.Victories
                        };
```

Comment: Doh! This was so simple.  The group by with the commas was the only thing I was actually missing from my original attempts.  I knew I could group by 1 property just fine but not the others nor did I imagine the result would be just what I needed.  Thanks

Comment: Actually, getting all sorts of issues when attempting to compile this.  Doesn't like the "group by" at all.

Comment: @Sailing  try `group mt by {mt.Tier, mt.Class, mt.TankName} into g`

Comment: Yes, tried that.  Still no go.  Produces numerous "Invalid expression term '{'" errors, and "; expected" errors.  13 errors all on that line with the group by.  Still researching.

Comment: `group mt by new {mt.Tier, mt.Class, mt.TankName} into g` and `Wins = g.Sum(mt=> mt.Victories)`

Comment: @Magnus, thanks. The "new" was the issue.  Already had spotted the missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use Method syntax. This should give you the same as @TheEvilGreebo

```
var result = memberTanks.GroupBy(x => new {x.Tier, x.Class, x.TankName})
                        .Select(g => new { g.Key.Tier, 
                                           g.Key.Class, 
                                           g.Key.TankName, 
                                           Fights = g.Sum(mt => mt.Battles), 
                                           Wins = g.Sum(mt=> mt.Victories)
                        });
```

Which syntax you use comes down to preference.
Remove the .Select to return the IGrouping which will enable you to enumerate the groups

```
var result = memberTanks.GroupBy(x => new {x.Tier, x.Class, x.TankName})
```

Answer (score 1):

I kept trying to get useful results our of the The Evil Greebo's answer.  While the answer does yield results (after fixing the compilation issues mentioned in responses) it doesn't give me what I was *really* looking for (meaning I didn't explain myself well enough in the question).

Feanz left a comment in my question to check out the MS site with LINQ examples and, even though I thought I had looked there before, this time I found their example of nested group bys and I tried it their way.  The following code gives me exactly what I was looking for:

```
var result = from mt in db.MemberTanks
             group mt by mt.Tier into tg
             select new
             {
                 Tier = tg.Key,
                 Classes = from mt in tg
                           group mt by mt.Class into cg
                           select new
                           {
                               Class = cg.Key,
                               TankTypes = from mt in cg
                                           group mt by mt.TankName into tng
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               TankName = tng.Key,
                                               Battles = tng.Sum(mt => mt.Battles),
                                               Victories = tng.Sum(mt => mt.Victories),
                                               Count = tng.Count()
                                           }
                           }
             };
```

I'll leave the answer by Mr. Greebo checked as most people will likely get the best results from that.

Comment: Well, the results from the previous answers ultimately yielded a single, non-nested result set. The intellisense implied the results would be multiple nested groups, but when I ran the code the result set was a single list.  The code in my answer makes very distinct groups with each grouping in its own result set nested where I expected them to be.

Comment: I removed some of my answer as I changed my mind about marking my own response as the correct answer. Greebo's answer got the most upvotes and while it didn't exactly fit what I needed, its still correct and will most likely fit future answer seekers better.